# Scheduled Flutter Local Notifications not showing even after permission granted

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I'm working on a Flutter application where I'm trying to schedule and show local notifications using the flutter_local_notifications package. I have ensured that the required permissions are granted, but the notifications are still not appearing.

I have tried normal notificaiton and they are showing but when I try to schedule notifications nothing shows up.

I've checked and confirmed notification permissions.
Checked logs for any errors or warnings related to notifications.

Code:

I initialize the time zones and set up the notifications as follows:
main.dart

```
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  NotificationService().initNotification();
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
```

here is the notification_settings.dart

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> showTestNotification() async {
    // Check if notifications are granted
    final bool? isGranted = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.areNotificationsEnabled();

    if (!isGranted!) {
      print("Notifications are not granted");
      AppSettings.openAppSettings();
      return;
    }

    print("Notifications are granted");

    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails('your_channel_id', 'your_channel_name', importance: Importance.max, priority: Priority.high, showWhen: false);

    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      0,
      'Test Notification',
      'This is a test notification after 5 seconds',
      tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
  }
```

here is the button to trigger

```
OutlinedButton(
                  onPressed: showTestNotification,
                  child: Text("Schedule 5-sec Notification"),
                ),
```

I am not sure why it is not working however when I try the below code it works:

```
                OutlinedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _notificationService.showNotification(
                      id: 1,
                      title: 'Hi',
                      body: 'This is a test notification.',
                    );
                  },
```

notification service:

```
class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initNotification() async {
    AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = const AndroidInitializationSettings('flutter');

    var initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings(
        requestAlertPermission: true, requestBadgePermission: true, requestSoundPermission: true, onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {});

    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings, onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {});
  }

  notificationDetails() {
    return const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'channelId',
          'channelName',
          importance: Importance.max,
        ),
        iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails());
  }

  Future showNotification({int id = 0, String? title, String? body, String? payLoad}) async {
    return notificationsPlugin.show(id, title, body, await notificationDetails());
  }
```

Comment: Can you add more tracing to verify each call is being executed as expected in ShowTestNotification? Also, what state is your app in when scheduled notifications are not working as expected? 

Refer to documentation here about constraints of scheduled notifications on some devices/states:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#scheduled-android-notifications

Smaller detail, but noticed a name difference in a parameter (payload vs. payLoad) in your notification service between the method name and call.